# Can I make a Bootstrap width responsive

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a button which I set it's width to `w-25` but as the screen gets smaller I want to remove that 25 I tried `w-sm-25` but it did not work is there a way for me to do it.

Comment: Please accept the answer so others know the question is solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are 2 ways...

1 - use the grid (`col-sm-3` in 25% width)...

```
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Button</button>
        </div>
   </div>
```

***or***

2 - add a CSS class and media query...

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .w-sm-25 {
        width: 25%;
    }
}
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/p/JAwMbu8O16